# Kong Ingress Controller Clarification

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong

When I went through thsis [doc](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/deploy/minikube.md) for implementing KONG Ingress Controller for Kubernetes, It was mentioned

> One of the main features provided by an Ingress controller is the
>   ability to react to changes in the Kubernetes cluster. This means if
>   we scale a deployment or a pod dies we need to update the Kong
>   configuration (a Target in this case)

They say that they regularly check for changes in a POD and update the KONG UPSTREAM's TARGET accordingly. My Question is, this is what a Service in Kubernetes is designed for, Why not point directly to the Service **ClusterIP** and **Port** itself which will act as Internal Service Discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from Kong ingress controller [readme](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller):

> Why endpoints and not services
>
> The Kong ingress controller does not use Services to route traffic to
>   the pods. Instead it uses the Endpoints API to bypass kube-proxy to
>   allow Kong features like session affinity and custom load balancing
>   algorithms. It also removes overhead, such as conntrack entries for
>   iptables DNAT.